# How do I drink milk in Feed The Beast?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing FTB Unhinged with some other mods thrown in, and whenever I attempt to drink a milk bucket, it pours the milk on the ground as if it were water. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried raising it up so that it can't touch any blocks?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ no, good idea! This seems rather stupid however, as your most likely to be poisoned in a mineshaft, where your in an extremely enclosed area, and likely to target a block no matter where you point...

Comment: @jeffreylin_ no go, the answer worked tho

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are various mods that make milk a proper liquid that can be poured, so to drink it requires bottles.

Hover over the bucket of milk in your inventory and press U for crafting recipes. There is probably one involving bottles.